# How to unsubscribe DocumentSaved Event in Idling Event and go out of the function?

Tags: revit-api, revit

I have a problem regarding events in Revit.Even I unsubscribe the DocumentSaved Event in Idling Event, the control of the program don't go outside of the DocumentSaved Event function, thereby making a call to DocumentSaved Event indefinitely.

Here is the code segment-

```
        Application application = sender as Application;
        if (!e.Document.IsFamilyDocument)
        {
            //selectedChoice = 3;
            UIApplication uIApplication = new UIApplication(application);
            ProjectSpecificInfo projectSpecificInfo = new ProjectSpecificInfo();
            AddinEntryPoint.saveStopWatch.Stop();
            AddinEntryPoint.mainSchema.projectSpecificInfo.TryGetValue(e.Document.PathName, out projectSpecificInfo);
            projectSpecificInfo.saveFileDuration = AddinEntryPoint.saveStopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
            //if (needToExportTheDataAndCallAPI.TryGetValue(e.Document.PathName, out bool needToExport))
            //{
            //    needToExportTheDataAndCallAPI[e.Document.PathName] = true;
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    needToExportTheDataAndCallAPI.Add(e.Document.PathName, true);
            //}

            if (!AddinEntryPoint.mainSchema.projectSpecificInfo.ContainsKey(e.Document.PathName))
            {
                AddinEntryPoint.mainSchema.projectSpecificInfo.Add(e.Document.PathName, projectSpecificInfo);
            }
            else
            {
                projectSpecificInfo = AddinEntryPoint.mainSchema.projectSpecificInfo[e.Document.PathName];
            }
            projectSpecificInfo.saveFileDuration = AddinEntryPoint.saveStopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
            //projectSpecificInfo = AddinEntryPoint.ChangeProjectSpecificValues(uIApplication.ActiveUIDocument, projectSpecificInfo);
            //projectSpecificInfo.RevitVersion = application.VersionName;
            //projectSpecificInfo.SubRevitVersion = application.SubVersionNumber;
            AddinEntryPoint.mainSchema.projectSpecificInfo[e.Document.PathName] = projectSpecificInfo;


            if (!AddinEntryPoint.mainSchema.userSpecificInfo.ContainsKey(Environment.MachineName))
            {
                AddinEntryPoint.mainSchema.userSpecificInfo.Add(Environment.MachineName, AddinEntryPoint.mainSchema.projectSpecificInfo);
            }
            else
            {
                AddinEntryPoint.mainSchema.projectSpecificInfo = AddinEntryPoint.mainSchema.userSpecificInfo[Environment.MachineName];
            }

            //Utils.PopulateVisualizationDataToMap(uIApplication.ActiveUIDocument);

            if (!e.Document.IsWorkshared)
                Utils.ExportVisualizationDataToJsonAndCallAPI();
        }
        e.Dispose();
        application.DocumentSaved -= Application_DocumentSaved;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your call to retrieve the application from the `sender` argument may give you a different instance than the one that originally subscribed to `DocumentSaved`. Hence, the unsubscription has no effect. I suggest that you save the application instance that originally subscribed to `DocumentSaved` in a global variable somewhere and use that same instance to unsubscribe again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your suggestion but it's still not coming out of the event.